# Symlinks in shared folder of virtual box with Windows 10 host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, symlink

I am running a linux (ubuntu) system within a virtual box container. I used symlinks in the shared directory, which needed some extra work as described here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085

This worked very well for my requirements running a Windows 8 host. Now, I switched to Windows 10 and the symlinks do not work any more. I am still able to create symlinks, but the correct path cannot be resolved.

Using readlink, I can see that the created symlink is wrong. If I create a symlink with

```
ln -s /media/data/jquery.js /media/data/test.js
```

the returned value with readlink is

```
\media\data\jquery.js
```

Obviously, the directory separator is incorrect. If I create a symlink outside the shared directory (to the same file on the shared directory), the path is correct.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the incorrect directory separator?

Mathias

Comment: Try new version from here (currently 5.0.3)
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

I have similar issue, today installed this update and it looks it works, more or less, for me. Specify full path for target dir/file.

Comment: You might need to launch VirtualBox in administrator mode, horrifying as that sounds.